# A general way to approach this bounded limit question

Tags: real-analysis

> if $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is bounded , then there exists a $M>0$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$  it satisfies $|a_n| \leq |a_1|+(n-1)M$

What I did was:

1. I tried Proof by contradiction and assumed $|a_n| > |a_1|+(n-1)M$ then if we assume $n=1$ or any $n$ we will get $|a_n| >|a_n|$ which is false
2. Second thing was proof by induction so we need to prove that every $n$ satisfies the following : $|a_n| \leq |a_1|+(n-1)M$

Assume $n=1$ we get $|a_1| \leq |a_1|$ which is correct

then assume $n=k+1$ we get $|a_{k+1}| = |a_{k+1} -a_k +a_k|$ and according to the triangle inequality we get $|a_{k+1} -a_k +a_k| \leq |a_{k+1} -a_k|+|a_k| \leq M+ |a_1| + (k-1)M = |a_1| +kM$

the proof by induction is what is written in the book and it is understandable but I am asking if there is another way to try and prove this for example according to the bounded sequence definition which is what I tried at first

Given $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ bounded then there exists $|a_{n+1} -a_n|<M$ for every $ n \in \Bbb N$ but from here I could not continue as I do not have a way to continue it..

Thanks for any help and tips

Comment: You can do the proof by contradiction. Suppose you have $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < M$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but you have $|a_n| - |a_1| > (n - 1)M$ as you were saying. Do do you see how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $M>0$ such that for all $n \ge 1$, $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<M$.

Then using the triangular inequality the fact that for all $n \ge 1$, $a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k) = a_n$

We get that for all $n \ge 1$ :

$$|a_{n}| \le |a_1| + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a_{k+1}-a_k| \le |a_1| + (n-1) M $$

Comment: Thank you for the help , can you explain how you got to $a_1$ and the summation? isn't the triangle inequality $|x-y| \leq ||x| -|y||$ ?

Comment: $ |x-y| \geq ||x|-|y||$ *

Comment: @Adamrk You are talking about a consequence of the triangular inequality. The triangular inequality states that for all $x,y$ : $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$.